# Ajuda com uncheck

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema em meu código. Sou novo em jQuery. Ele está perfeito, consegui fazer quase tudo que eu queria, exceto por uma única coisa que não consigo resolver: não consigo fazer com que ele desmarque se clicado novamente, ficando como novo.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Pontos</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            .rating {
                overflow: hidden;
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                font-size:18px;
                color: #000000;
            }
            .rating-star {
                padding: 0 1px;
                margin: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                float: right;
            }
            .rating-star:after {
                position: relative;
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                content:'\f1db';
            }

            .rating-star.checked ~ .rating-star:after,
            .rating-star.checked:after {
                content:'\f111';
            }

            .rating:hover .rating-star:after {content:'\f1db';}

            .rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star:after, 
            .rating-star:hover:after {
                content:'\f111' !important;
            }


            /* Just for the demo */
            body {
                margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="rating">
            <span class="rating-star" data-value="5"></span>
            <span class="rating-star" data-value="4"></span>
            <span class="rating-star" data-value="3"></span>
            <span class="rating-star" data-value="2"></span>
            <span class="rating-star" data-value="1"></span>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('.rating-star').click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.rating').find('.rating-star').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).addClass('checked');

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal para resolver o teu problema é a utilização dos elementos do tipo "radio" do HTML.

Por exemplo:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
</fieldset>
```

Desta maneira no Javascript tu pode buscar o elemento selecionado da seguinte maneira:

```
$('.rating :input').each(function (index,element) {
    if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
        value = $(element).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, eu tentei de inicio como "radio", mais infelizmente não consegui obter o resultado que queria, não consegui editar completamente os botoes radio, não sei se por falta de experiencia e conhecimento. Os botoes quando marcados na hora da impressão eles apresentavam a imagem natural deles diferenciando, completamente do design do documento. Mais de qualquer forma muito obrigado, vou estudar mais os botoes "radio".

Answer (score 0):

Faça isso criando uma variável que grava o valor da opção clicada. No caso, eu criei a variável `current_value = 0;` que terá o valor inicial `0`.

Quando uma opção for clicada, essa variável irá receber o valor clicado correspondente. Se a mesma opção for clicada novamente, todas as opções são desmarcadas e a variável volta para `0`.

O código ficou assim:

```js
current_value = 0;
$('.rating-star').click(function(){
 clicked_value = $(this).attr("data-value");
 if(current_value != clicked_value){
        $('.rating .rating-star').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
  current_value = clicked_value;
 }else{
        $('.rating .rating-star').removeClass('checked');
  current_value = 0;
 }
 $("#teste").html(current_value); // só exemplo
});
```

```css
.rating {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 font-size:18px;
 color: #000000;
}
.rating-star {
 padding: 0 1px;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
.rating-star:after {
 position: relative;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 content:'\f1db';
}

.rating-star.checked ~ .rating-star:after,
.rating-star.checked:after {
 content:'\f111';
}

.rating:hover .rating-star:after {content:'\f1db';}

.rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star:after, 
.rating-star:hover:after {
 content:'\f111' !important;
}


/* Just for the demo */
body {
 margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="rating">
    <span class="rating-star" data-value="5"></span>
    <span class="rating-star" data-value="4"></span>
    <span class="rating-star" data-value="3"></span>
    <span class="rating-star" data-value="2"></span>
    <span class="rating-star" data-value="1"></span>
</div>
<!-- abaixo é só para mostrar o valor clicado -->
<br />
Opção atual: <b id="teste">0</b>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou também assim como a primeira opção do amigo Sergio, não precisando mexer no css. Muito obrigado mesmo a ideia de criar a variável atribuindo um valor, realmente abriu um novo campo de ideias e possibilidades para meu projeto.

Comment: @ErickFontes De nada amigo! Que bom que ajudou. Abs!

Comment: Pergunta esse valor atribuído, se eu adicionasse, outro item desse abaixo, eles se somariam ou seriam independentes um do outro? se sim, eu poderia trabalhar com esse valor livremente para outras funções né?

Comment: @ErickFontes Pra cada coisa teria que criar uma variável diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar `$(this).toggleClass('checked');` para colocar ou retirar a classe como um interruptor.

Exemplo:

```js
$('.rating-star').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('checked');
  $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.rating {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
}

.rating-star {
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.rating-star:after {
  position: relative;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f1db';
}

.rating-star.checked~.rating-star:after,
.rating-star.checked:after {
  content: '\f111';
}

.rating:hover .rating-star:after {
  content: '\f1db';
}

.rating-star:hover~.rating-star:after,
.rating-star:hover:after {
  content: '\f111' !important;
}


/* Just for the demo */

body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="rating">
  <span class="rating-star" data-value="5"></span>
  <span class="rating-star" data-value="4"></span>
  <span class="rating-star" data-value="2"></span>
  <span class="rating-star" data-value="3"></span>
  <span class="rating-star" data-value="1"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, exatamente o que eu precisava. muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @ErickFontes ótimo! Se quiseres podes clicar para marcar a resposta como aceite.